# How do i retrieve just the child-object in Azure Cosmos using mongoose and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using Azure cosmos db with the Mongodb API. Also i am using mongoose to create schemas and create new documents in the database. I am also using Node.js.

At this point I am considering using a One-to-Many relationship with embedded documents.

The data structure is like this :

```
{
    "_id" : "locality1",
    "_type" : "Locality",
    "name" : "Wallmart",
    "subsectionList" : [
        {
            "_id" : "subsection1",
            "_type" : "SubSection",
            "name" : "First floor",
            "sensorList" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "sensor1",
                            "_type" : "Sensor",
                    "placement" : "In the hallway"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : "sensor2",
                            "_type" : "Sensor",
                    "placement" : "In the ceiling"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "subsection2",
            "_type" : "SubSection",
            "name" : "Second floor",
            "sensorList" : [ ],
        }
    ],
}
```

I want to retrieve ONLY the "sensor1"-object, not anything from the parent.

Using querying i am only able to retrieve the entire "locality1"-object, with all its underlying subsections and sensors. On a larger scale that is an unnecessary large amount of data.

Here is my query so far.

```
Locality.find().where('subsectionList.sensorList._id').equals("sensor1").then(doc => {
    console.log(doc)
  })
```

I appreciate any tips! :)

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, i can't get rid of the `_id` property anyway even though i followed the parameters which is mentioned [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

```
Locality.find({},'subsectionList', function (err, locas)
```

The above query still return the results including `_id` property.(It seems a default item)

I get a workaround from this [blog](https://coderwall.com/p/6v5rcw/querying-sub-documents-and-sub-sub-documents-in-mongoose) that you could loop the array to filter your desired columns.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var COSMOSDB_CONNSTR= "mongodb://***.documents.azure.com:10255/db";
var COSMODDB_USER= "***";
var COSMOSDB_PASSWORD= "***";

mongoose.connect(COSMOSDB_CONNSTR+"?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb", {
  auth: {
    user: COSMODDB_USER,
    password: COSMOSDB_PASSWORD
  }
}).then(() => console.log('Connection to CosmosDB successful'))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));

const Locality = mongoose.model('Locality', new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    subsectionList: [{
        sensorList: [{
            _id: String,
            _type: String,
            placement: String
        }]
    }]
}));

Locality.find({},'subsectionList', function (err, locas) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  var returnArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<locas.length;i++){
      for(var j = 0; j<locas[i].subsectionList.length;j++){
          for(var k = 0; k<locas[i].subsectionList[j].sensorList.length;k++){
           if(locas[i].subsectionList[j].sensorList[k]._id == 'sensor1')
             returnArray.push(locas[i].subsectionList[j].sensorList[k]);
          }
      }
  }
  console.log(returnArray);
});
```

[image]